# Switch between two jQuery functions after some time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to switch between this two functions every 5 seconds. The function changes the background image of a website in an :after element. 
I think I have to do it like this because there is no other way to access :after elements with jQuery. So it should work like a slideshow.

How can I achieve this?

```
function one(){  
var value = "url('/img/img1.png')"
$( "<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )
}

function two(){  
var value = "url('/img/img2.jpg')"
$( "<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>" ).appendTo( "head" )
}
```

Comment: Use setinterval to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this kind of task Javascript/jQuery is not really necessary: you could  use a `CSS` animation. E.g.:

```css
#showcase::after {
   content: "";
   background-size: cover;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   animation: switchbg 10s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes switchbg {
  0%, 49.99% { background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/2000/1000) }
  50%, 100% { background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/1000/500) }
}
```

```html
<div id="showcase"></div>
```

Comment: This worked just as I wanted, I wonder why I did not think about this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Appending style after style block to the head of the document is not great practice.

A better way to achieve this is to toggle a class on the element `#showcase`.

jQuery comes with a function for that already called: `toggleClass`.

https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

So you could do something like:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    $('#showcase').toggle('background2');
}, 5000);
```

Then you simply control the backgrounds for `#showcase` with and without the `background2` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you build an array containing your functions, you can loop through and around this array with a `setInterval`

If you want to add more functions, you can just add them to the `bgImageFunctions` array

```js
function one () {
  let value = "url('/img/img1.png')"
  console.log("<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>")
  // $("<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>").appendTo("head")
}

function two () {
  let value = "url('/img/img2.jpg')"
  console.log("<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>")
  // $("<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>").appendTo("head")
}

var bgImageFunctions = [ one, two ];
var bgImageIndex = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  bgImageFunctions[bgImageIndex++ % bgImageFunctions.length]();
}, 5000);
```

You can also do this with one function, by passing the new URL as a parameter

```js
function updateBackground (value) {
  console.log("<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>")
  // $("<style>#showcase:after { background-image: " + value + "; }</style>").appendTo("head")
}

var bgImageLinks = [ "url('/img/img1.png')", "url('/img/img2.jpg')" ];
var bgImageIndex = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
  updateBackground(bgImageLinks[bgImageIndex++ % bgImageLinks.length]);
}, 5000);
```